# React save api requests

Tags: reactjs

I am building a small online shopping web app and I have about 10 categories of products e.g. Mens, Womens, Kids etc. I want to memoize the requests. My question is how do I do it? I read about `useCallback` hook and I believe that I should use it here, but at the same time since there are like 10 categories how do I keep track for which category should I get from the cache and for which should I make the request? I have just considering declaring `useState` hooks for each category and change state for each depending on selected category.

```
const [productsMensCategory, setProductsMensCategory] = useState([]);
const [productsWomensCategory, setProductsWomensCategory] = useState([]);
const [productsKidsCategory, setProductsKidsCategory] = useState([]);
```

I have also been thinking that Redux might be useful here.

Could anyone please guide me a bit here, I would like to know how to approach this.

This is how I make a request.

```
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getProducts = async (category: string) => {
      try {
        const response = await getCategoryProducts(category);
        console.log(response);

        if (response.status === 200) {
          setProducts(response.data);
        }
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
      }
    };

    getProducts(handleChangeCategory(section));
  }, [section, setProducts]);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want these to stay saved even if you reload page you could use `localStorage` to make it easy. Redux would be a nice approach to not make another request, but as far as you reload it won't save state.

`UseCallback` only memorizes a callback, so if re-render happens this callback remains the same, it only changes if a dependency from its dependencies array changes

Answer (score 1):

Good idea to have the data memoized. In my opinion, if at all you can get the data with flags based on date_modified for each category (as server response) you can then set or not set component state.

Something like below

```
if (response.status === 200 && category_flag_from_server !== current_category_flag_from_state) {
    setProducts(response.data);
}
```

Comment: Can please  provide more details here ```category_flag_from_server !== current_category_flag_from_state``` I do not quite get it. Do we just check if category search has changed?

Comment: Yes correct, I was thinking of same thing. Basically, from server response you can retrieve a flag and check it with the flag which is stored in your current state (which can be a modified date & time). In this way you can avoid resetting the current state again and again. Also, I thought of saving the api request, but I think that is unavoidable, since you need the response from server for different categories.

Comment: I want to make as few requests to the server as possible. What I image here is something like check if current state for current category has any data, then make the request and set state for this category, else if we have data for this category, then do not make the request and just retrieve what we have in state. ```I thought of saving the api request, but I think that is unavoidable``` do you suggest it should not be done like this?

Comment: In case you want the data/categories to be refreshed or updated you need to make API call. I assume this is also what is required here, Isn't it? In case you want to save the http request, you can check for the data existence + check and set a cookie with expiry. Once the cookie is expired and not available, then you can allow the http request to be entertained for getting the fresh data (even if there is data available in current state).